# Post data from aurelia form into asp.net controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, aurelia

I can read data and display it on aurelia-SPA like this:

In my ASP.NET controller I have:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<Team> Teams()
{
    var Teams = _teamRepository.GetAllTeams().OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    return Teams;
}
```

On aurelia-page typescript file I can  then read data like this:

```
@inject(HttpClient)
export class Fetchdata {

    public Teams: Teams[] | undefined;

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        http.fetch('api/SampleData/Teams')
            .then(result => result.json() as Promise<Teams[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.Teams = data;
            });
    }
```

And then in aurelia-page html file I can show the data like this:

```
<template>
    <h1>Teams in database</h1>
    <p if.bind="!Teams"><em>Loading...</em></p> 
    <table if.bind="Teams" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>TeamName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr repeat.for="team of Teams">
                <td>${ team.name }</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

This works fine. Now I cannot find any example on how to create a simple form and post data from it to the ASP.NET controller. For example If my aurelia html would contain a form like this:

```
<form role="form" submit.delegate="postdata()">
    <label for="name">Teamn Name</label>
    <input type="text" value.bind="name" placeholder="Name">

    <label for="teamurl">TeamUrl</label>
    <input type="text" value.bind="teamurl" placeholder="Teamurl">

    <button type="submit">Add Team to DB</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view model which corresponds to the view with the form you have in your question - you would need to implement your `postdata()` method. Given that the view model has `HttpClient` injected and assigned to the property called `http` and properties called `name` and `teamurl` declared on this same view model and there is a property called `postPath` value of which is the url for your post endpoint - `postdata` method would look something like this:

```
public async postdata(): Promise<bool> {
  if (!this.name || !this.teamurl) {
    return; // no valid data. abort.
  }

  // given that there is a type called Team and it has a constructor which 
  // takes corresponding parameters - init up a new instance of Team with
  // current name and teamurl values
  let payload = new Team(this.name, this.teamurl); 

  try {
    await this.http.fetch(postPath, {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    }).then(response => response.json());
    // return true if no error, there might be a need for more complicated logic here
    // depending on what your post endpoint returns
    return true;
  } catch(e: Exception) {
    console.log("Error: ", e.Message); // handle the error logging however you need.
    return false;
  }
}
```